# I cant load admob rewaeded videos in my android app

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I am using this code but it always write
`W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3`
in the logcat..

```
RewardedVideoAd m2Ad = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    m2Ad.loadAd("ca-app-pub-#########", adRequest);  
    if (m2Ad.isLoaded()) {
        m2Ad.show();
    }
```

Comment: share the complete code...

Comment: there is something wrong with my code,, i need the full right code to test if it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are running app in debug mode then you should use these Ad Unit ID according to [Google Mobile Ads SDK Team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/k-kVwVu2XBc)

For Reward Videos, the following are our test Ad Unit ID

```
iOS - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313
Android - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
```

Note that Reward Video Ad Unit IDs are platform specific.

Comment: you are testing on what?

Comment: dubging the app in my phone not emulater

Comment: try changing the phone and check the internet connection as well. ads sometimes doesn't work on debug mode. Try installing released apk on phone